# Troubleshooting Linking External CSS

Tags: css

I've attached a screenshot of the code I'm using to link to the CSS files on my server. Am I using the wrong path??

The site I'm working on is http://www.bookslibrarianslove.com/index.php/Pages

Many Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are. And your question is almost off topic.

- EECMS variables are put between `{` and `}`. You should put variables there, not only paths. [Path variables](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/path.html#path-variables) are a little different. You can study all about it on [Template Language Overview](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/overview.html);
- `public_html` is usually the folder where the website is. Everything accessible from web is inside this folder, so you need to point to its contents, not to the folder itself;
- paths initiating with `/` are followed from the domain root. They're called "root relative paths". For example, `/my-file.gif` can be accessed from anywhere on the domain;
- paths without a `/` as first character are followed starting at the folder you already are. They're the "relative paths". For example, if you are on `http://domain.com/page_1/page_23`, a path like `my-file.gif` will point to `http://domain.com/page_1/page_23/my-file.gif`. They can give you headaches;
- paths starting with protocol and domain are called "absolute paths";
- CSS can be saved as a [EECMS Template](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/design/templates/new_template.html) and linked using [`{stylesheet='template_group/css_template'}`](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/stylesheet.html), but you usually don't need that;

Since the CSS isn't being served by EECMS, you can point directly to it in two ways. Using a root relative path:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" />
```

Or an absolute path:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{site_url}/css/style.css" />
```

EECMS will replace the `{site_url}` variable with the setting used on [URL to the root directory of your site](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/general_configuration.html#url-to-the-root-directory-of-your-site) on Control Panel. Pay attention to not have double `/` or a missing one.

Comment: Robson, off-topic comment... you use the English contraction "you're" incorrectly. No one says "you're" in place of "you are" in sentence termination in it's 2nd person singular present context. It's very confusing, no one expects "you're" to not have a following adjective, so it sounds like you're ending your sentences with "your", even when reading it.  :P

Answer (score 0):

Nope! , erm, I mean Yup! You have the wrong value for the `src` parameter.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{site_url}css/style.css" />
```

Use that (assuming this is an ExpressionEngine parsed template). You might need to add a `/` after `{site_url}`, depending on what your site url config var is set to.

Comment: Thank you @jrothafer. BTW, I sent you an invite on LinkedIn.

Comment: Okay, I'm still tinkering with this issue, and have provided an updated screen shot.

Comment: Dot to the dot dot (...) your new screen shot shows that this template is not getting parsed by ExpressionEngine at all. Is it a template in a template group? That is set to "Website" as type, instead of say "CSS" or something else? Let me clear this up, go and edit this page, and **take a screenshot of you editing it**, and add that to your question.

Comment: Wait, wait wait... why are your styles sheets in a `<noscript>` block??

Comment: The code lives in the PageElements/.header template

Comment: Yes, the Type is currently set to Web Page

Comment: Ooookay... I can get your CSS to resolve, but not your JS. Is all of your stylesheets in a template group called `css`? and all your JS in a template group called `js`? (Most people don't actually put their CSS and JS in template groups inside of ExpressionEngine) There's quite possible a big issue with the fact that you're not removing `index.php` in your paths... https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/urls/remove_index.php.html

Comment: I removed the <noscript> block in the original template (Strongly Typed by HTML5 Up). Thx! Would love to hear how CSS resolved. I did have the CSS and JS template groups in EE but switched to pulling them from the server.

Comment: It was working @ domain.com/index.php/css/whatever.css , but now it's 404'ing. I'm trying to follow how you want to go about this, but I think one issue might be your site settings... https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/general_configuration.html#url-to-the-root-directory-of-your-site .. make sure youre url-root doesn't have index.php following it.. I don't want to screw you up more, you might want to start a new question or continue to edit your question and fill in more details (site config stuff, htaccess stuff, etc...)

Comment: Update: The index page code was still inking to the other .html pages in the Strongly Typed theme; be sure to delete those and add the path variables to your EE templates, upload link pic icons into EE DB etc. Cheers!

Comment: Excellent! It's looking in much better shape now.